# Is it possible to set display configuration programmatically on login time?

Tags: ltsp, ltsp-client

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server with fat LTSP clients with graphical MATE Desktop Environment.

Some of clients have two display ports (DVI and VGA) on integrated Intel graphics card.
On some of them Ubuntu incorrectly selects main screen.

Is it possible to set display configuration programmatically on login time?
I mean setting it by `mate-display-properties` once and then load this settings on the selected clients. Is `xrandr` better?

My current plan is:

1. Manually configure problematic clients with `mate-display-properties` after login;
2. Write down MAC- and/or IP- addresses of problematic clients;
3. Change lts.conf to keep constant login names for these MACs and/or IPs.

Maybe there is a simpler solution?
How can I set display options on these clients with `xrandr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using LightDM,
Edit the config file at /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.d/
Mine is 01_debian.conf, but I suspect yours will be 01_ubuntu.conf

Add: `display-setup-script=xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary`
replace HDMI1 with the name of the monitor you want to use.

Note: if the server doesn't have a custom setup for LightDM, the above line can be added to /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Comment: On LTSP I'm using `ldm` (LTSP display manager). But anyway thanks for the `xrandr` part!